# How the following closed form expression is obtained?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

I came across the following closed form expression :

$g(\mu, \nu) = \sum_{\mathcal{j}\in\mathcal{U}}\underset{i}{\rm max}\bigl(\text{log}(\epsilon_{ij})-\mu_i\bigr)+\sum_{i\in\mathcal{B}}e^{\mu_i-\nu_iP_i^s-1}+\sum_{i\in \mathcal{B}}v_iP_i^G$ ---(A)

The closed form expression (A) is obtained after substituting eq (1) and eq (2) into eq (B),
\begin{equation}
  g(\mu, \nu)=\begin{cases}
    \underset{X,K}{\rm max}\sum_{j\in\mathcal{U}}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{B}}x_{ij}\text{log}(\epsilon_{ij})-\sum_{i\in \mathcal{B}}K_i\text{log}(K_i)-\sum_{i\in \mathcal{B}}\mu_i\biggl(\sum_{j\in \mathcal{U}}x_{ij}-K_i\biggr)-\sum_{i\in \mathcal{B}}v_i\bigl(K_iP_i^s-P_i^G\bigr)& \\
\text{such that} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{B}}x_{ij} = 1, x_{ij}\in \{0,1\}, \forall j, \forall i    ----(B)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

And
\begin{equation}
  x_{ij}^*=\begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if $i=i^*$}.\\
    0, & \text{if $i\neq i^*$ }.---(1)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Also,
$K_i^* = e^{\mu_i-\nu_iP_i^s-1}$ ---(2)

I tried substituting (2) and (1) into (B) but not getting expression (A) properly. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Note that $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{B}$ are set, $X,K$ are matrix and $\mu, \nu$ are vectors.

Comment: Welcome. “How is the following closed form expression obtained?” Is followed by: “...is obtained”. So, what you need help with is unclear. What’s especially unclear is *what do all the letters mean*? People outside of your class / textbook / etc. might not recognise this notation

Comment: I am getting confused as I am not able to understand how to substitute the cases that are in equation (1)....